# Windows error using graphics.h

Tags: c++, c, windows, graphics, bgi

I am trying to use the graphics.h library for C/C++ to get pixel values from some images. The program compiles without any errors or warnings but when I try to execute it, a window is opened with the following message: "version2.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenient".

My code:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Macros to set important values for
*  size and number of images
*/
#define IMAGES 9
#define WIDTH 200
#define HEIGTH 225

/* Receives the image number and load it using
 * readimagefile() function from BGI libary.
 */
void loadImage(int imageNumber);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int row, column, image;
  int red[HEIGTH][WIDTH][IMAGES], green[HEIGTH][WIDTH][IMAGES], blue[HEIGTH][WIDTH][IMAGES];
  int pixelValue;
  int finalWindow, currentWindow;


  for (image = 0; image < IMAGES; ++image)
  {
    currentWindow = initwindow(WIDTH, HEIGTH, "current"); // creates window to receive image
    setcurrentwindow(currentWindow); // set recent window as the current window
    loadImage(image);

    for (row = 0; row < HEIGTH; ++row)
    {
      for (column = 0; column < WIDTH; ++column)
      {
          pixelValue = getpixel(row, column);
          green[column][row][image] = GREEN_VALUE(pixelValue);
          red[column][row][image] = RED_VALUE(pixelValue);
          blue[column][row][image]= BLUE_VALUE(pixelValue);
      }
    }
  }

  getch();

  return 0;

}

void loadImage(int imageNumber)
{
 char str[5];
 sprintf(str, "%i.jpg", imageNumber);
 readimagefile(str, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGTH);
}
```

Comment: what does gdb says ?

Comment: The `red`, `green` and `blue` arrays will use nearly 5 MB of stack space. Probably more than the default for Windows programs. You could try to move them to the static area outside of main.

Comment: In `loadImage` you don't reserve any space for the null byte.

Comment: @BoPersson it works now! I've moved the arrays and it's working! I didn't know about this stack space limit. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you should discover the image size and depth from the file, and *then* allocate sufficient memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`graphics.h` refers to the MS DOS graphics library "BGI", by Borland. It is only supported by Borland DOS compilers and cannot get ported to another OS, save for the old Windows versions like Windows 95/98 that still supported DOS.

Answer (score -1):

graphics.h is a library used by Borlando compilers(turbo c for example) in the 1990s now the library is very outdated and not supported by major compilers .Instead of graphics.h you can use the graphics library function defined by your compiler.graphic function differ from compiler to compiler because they are not the part of standard c language,they are implemented differently by differnt compilers